# How to change flex column width while keeping item centered

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a flexbox in my HTML, and I have two columns. What I have trouble doing is changing the right column's width. If I set the width to, say, `width: 50%`, the `.container` is no longer centered on the page, and the Google Maps size is also changed. I am trying to shrink the `.container` size but keep the whole flexbox centered on the page and the size of the maps the same. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```css
#google-maps
{
    background: #FFFFFF;
}

.hours-and-location
{
}

#hours-and-location-container
{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: center;
    margin: 3em;
    width: 50%;
}

.column
{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    margin: 1em;
}

.locations
{
    width: 100%;
}

.page-title-header
{
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<h1 class="page-title-header">
    Hours and Locations
</h1>

<div id="hours-and-location-container">
    <iframe class="column" id="google-maps"
            src="https://www.google.com/maps/d/u/0/embed?mid=1_iD-tpjnLUFwGIWoEcsx05qBgbx112w&ehbc=2E312F"
            width="600" height="500">
    </iframe>

    <div class="hours-and-location">
        <div class="locations column">
            <h2>
                Locations
            </h2>
            <p>
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt
                ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
            </p>
            <p>
                Augue mauris augue neque gravida in. Est sit amet facilisis magna. In vitae turpis massa sed
                elementum tempus egestas sed.
            </p>
            <p>
                Lectus quam id leo in vitae turpis massa sed.
            </p>
            <p>
                Imperdiet proin fermentum leo vel orci porta non pulvinar. A iaculis at erat pellentesque adipiscing
                commodo elit at imperdiet. Semper eget duis at tellus at urna condimentum. Purus in massa tempor
                nec feugiat nisl.
            </p>
        </div>
        <div class="hours">

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're looking for this

```css
#google-maps
{
    background: #FFFFFF;
}

.hours-and-location
{
  width:40vh
}

#hours-and-location-container
{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items:center;
    margin: 3em;

}

.column
{

    margin: 1em;
}



.page-title-header
{
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<h1 class="page-title-header">
    Hours and Locations
</h1>

<div id="hours-and-location-container">
    <iframe class="column" id="google-maps"
            src="https://www.google.com/maps/d/u/0/embed?mid=1_iD-tpjnLUFwGIWoEcsx05qBgbx112w&ehbc=2E312F"
            width="600" height="500">
    </iframe>

    <div class="hours-and-location">
        <div class="locations column">
            <h2>
                Locations
            </h2>
            <p>
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt
                ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
            </p>
            <p>
                Augue mauris augue neque gravida in. Est sit amet facilisis magna. In vitae turpis massa sed
                elementum tempus egestas sed.
            </p>
            <p>
                Lectus quam id leo in vitae turpis massa sed.
            </p>
            <p>
                Imperdiet proin fermentum leo vel orci porta non pulvinar. A iaculis at erat pellentesque adipiscing
                commodo elit at imperdiet. Semper eget duis at tellus at urna condimentum. Purus in massa tempor
                nec feugiat nisl.
            </p>
        </div>
        <div class="hours">

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can assign a max- width on your flex div then wrap them in a another div that control to center them like below.

```css
#google-maps
{
    background: #FFFFFF;
}

.hours-and-location
{
}

#hours-and-location-container
{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: center;
    margin: 3em;
    max-width: 700px;
    gap: 10px;
    
}

.wrapper {
  display:flex;
  justify-content: center;
  }
  
.column
{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    margin: 1em;
}

.locations
{
    width: 100%;
}

.page-title-header
{
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<h1 class="page-title-header">
    Hours and Locations
</h1>
<div class="wrapper">
<div id="hours-and-location-container">
    <iframe class="column" id="google-maps"
            src="https://www.google.com/maps/d/u/0/embed?mid=1_iD-tpjnLUFwGIWoEcsx05qBgbx112w&ehbc=2E312F"
            width="600" height="500">
    </iframe>

    <div class="hours-and-location">
        <div class="locations column">
            <h2>
                Locations
            </h2>
            <p>
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt
                ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
            </p>
            <p>
                Augue mauris augue neque gravida in. Est sit amet facilisis magna. In vitae turpis massa sed
                elementum tempus egestas sed.
            </p>
            <p>
                Lectus quam id leo in vitae turpis massa sed.
            </p>
            <p>
                Imperdiet proin fermentum leo vel orci porta non pulvinar. A iaculis at erat pellentesque adipiscing
                commodo elit at imperdiet. Semper eget duis at tellus at urna condimentum. Purus in massa tempor
                nec feugiat nisl.
            </p>
        </div>
        <div class="hours">

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, I have given `margin: 0 auto;` for making it to centre in any width from left to right it always takes the element to centre from the left and right. I hope this might will help or you are looking for something else?

```css
#google-maps
{
    background: #FFFFFF;
}

.hours-and-location
{
}

#hours-and-location-container
{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: center;
    margin: 3em;
    width: 50%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.column
{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    margin: 1em;
}

.locations
{
    width: 100%;
}

.page-title-header
{
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<h1 class="page-title-header">
    Hours and Locations
</h1>

<div id="hours-and-location-container">
    <iframe class="column" id="google-maps"
            src="https://www.google.com/maps/d/u/0/embed?mid=1_iD-tpjnLUFwGIWoEcsx05qBgbx112w&ehbc=2E312F"
            width="600" height="500">
    </iframe>

    <div class="hours-and-location">
        <div class="locations column">
            <h2>
                Locations
            </h2>
            <p>
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt
                ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
            </p>
            <p>
                Augue mauris augue neque gravida in. Est sit amet facilisis magna. In vitae turpis massa sed
                elementum tempus egestas sed.
            </p>
            <p>
                Lectus quam id leo in vitae turpis massa sed.
            </p>
            <p>
                Imperdiet proin fermentum leo vel orci porta non pulvinar. A iaculis at erat pellentesque adipiscing
                commodo elit at imperdiet. Semper eget duis at tellus at urna condimentum. Purus in massa tempor
                nec feugiat nisl.
            </p>
        </div>
        <div class="hours">

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```